# pyqt convert enum value to key

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

Is it possible to convert a qt enum value to its key?

For example I'd like to get to get 'A4' from QPrinter class knowing that QPrinter.A4 = 0

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, you can do this using the `QMetaObject`:

```
m = QtGui.QFrame.staticMetaObject
m.enumerator(m.indexOfEnumerator('Shadow')).valueToKey(QtGui.QFrame.Sunken)
'Sunken'
```

However it appears that `QPrinter` hasn't exposed a meta object, so you'll have to do it by walking `QPrinter`'s attributes in Python (fortunately PyQt enums are subclasses of `int`, so can be identified by `isinstance`):

```
page_sizes = dict((n, x) for x, n in vars(QtGui.QPrinter).items() if
                  isinstance(n, QtGui.QPrinter.PageSize))
page_sizes[QtGui.QPrinter.A4]
'A4'
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `vars` and `isinstance` to build a two-way mapping of the enum:

```
>>> from PyQt4.QtGui import QPrinter
>>> pagesizes = {}
>>> for key, value in vars(QPrinter).iteritems():
...     if isinstance(value, QPrinter.PageSize):
...         pagesizes[key] = value
...         pagesizes[value] = key
... 
>>> pagesizes['A4']
0
>>> pagesizes[QPrinter.A4]
'A4'
>>> pagesizes[0]
'A4'
```

**UPDATE:**

It seems that `vars()` will not work with all versions of PyQt, but `dir()` may do. So a more robust solution might be:

```
>>> pagesizes = {}
>>> for key in dir(QPrinter):
...     value = getattr(QPrinter, key)
...     if isinstance(value, QPrinter.PageSize):
...         pagesizes[key] = value
...         pagesizes[value] = key
...
```

(NB: only tested with *pyqt-4.10.3/qt-4.8.5*, *pyqt-4.10/qt-5.1.1* and *pyqt-5.1/qt-5.1.1*)

Comment: This answer doesn't work in PyQt5 and Python3, even if you change iteritems() to items() for Python3.  The enum of paper sizes is apparently is not in the QPrinter class any longer?

Comment: Qt5.1 has QPrinterInfo.supportedSizesWithNames() but in Qt5.0.1 what is the solution?

Comment: @bootchk. This would appear to be a bug in PyQt5: all the other QPrinter enums and their enumerators show up in vars() - it's only PageSize that's now missing. I don't think there's any other way to generate the enum keys if they're not in QPrinter's `__dict__` (Qt's meta-object system is also no help here, because QPrinter isn't a QObject).

Comment: @bootchk. If you're still interested, I think I may have found a workaround: please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a function to do this based on ecatmur's answer:

```
def qenum_key(base, value):
    """Convert a Qt Enum value to its key as a string.

    Args:
        base: The object the enum is in, e.g. QFrame.
        value: The value to get.

    Return:
        The key associated with the value as a string, or None.
    """
    klass = value.__class__
    try:
        idx = klass.staticMetaObject.indexOfEnumerator(klass.__name__)
    except AttributeError:
        idx = -1
    if idx != -1:
        return klass.staticMetaObject.enumerator(idx).valueToKey(value)
    else:
        for name, obj in vars(base).items():
            if isinstance(obj, klass) and obj == value:
                return name
        return None
```

This first tries to get the value via the QMetaObject, and if that fails or no meta object exists, falls back on the pure Python method.

Answer (score 0):

This implementation is similar to [The Compiler's one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24228220) but finds out base class (QPrinter,
QFrame etc.) by itself.

```
import sys


def enum_key(enum_val, with_val=False):
    """
    Return name of Qt enum value.
    `enum_val` - enum value
    `with_val` (bool) - return value as part of name
    """
    enum_cls = enum_val.__class__
    parent = sys.modules.get(enum_cls.__module__)
    for i in enum_cls.__qualname__.split(".")[:-1]:
        parent = getattr(parent, i)
    m = getattr(parent, "staticMetaObject", None)
    if m:
        idx = m.indexOfEnumerator(enum_cls.__name__)
        name = m.enumerator(idx).valueToKey(enum_val)
    else:
        for n, val in vars(parent).items():
            if isinstance(val, enum_cls) and val == enum_val:
                name = n
                break
    return "%s (%d)" % (name, enum_val) if with_val else name

# from PyQt5 import QtPrintSupport
# print(enum_key(QtPrintSupport.QPrinter.A5, with_val=1))
# >> A5 (9)
```